# Deploy container images to kubernetes to google cloud from java/node js

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-repository

I am trying to do some experiments with Kubernetes in google cloud.

I have docker image in google cloud registry and need to deploy that image to a kubernetes cluster.

Here are the steps I need to perform.

1. Create a Kubernetes cluster.
2. Copy the image from GCR and deploy to Kubernetes cluster.
3. Expose the cluster to internet via load balancer.

I know, it is possible to do via google cloud sdk cli. Is there way to do these steps via Java/node js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a RESTful kubernetes-engine API:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/api-organization

e.g. create a cluster:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.zones.clusters/create

The container registry should be standard docker APIs.

Both Java and Node have kubernetes clients:

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java
https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client